# Bamboo - Clone a from Git repo during deploy stage

Tags: git, deployment, continuous-integration, gitlab, bamboo

During the deployment stage on machine 10.1.10.1:
I want to clone a gitlab repo(tester.git) during the deploy stage and replace the contents of the directory like '/home/ash/repo/(contents of tester.git)'.

I cant have any ssh keys setup on machine 10.1.10.1 as the machine might be terminated anytime.

Is there a way this can be done by bamboo during the deployment stage?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you wanted to clone a repo and modify the contents of the repository.

How about [installing a Bamboo remote agent](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-remote-agent-installation-guide-289276832.html) in that machine? so that you don't have to SSH into that machine.

Ónce you [set that remote agent as a dedicated agent](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/dedicating-an-agent-629015108.html) for your deployment project, you can use [Source code checkout task](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/checking-out-code-289277060.html) to clone the Git repository,
then using [Script task](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/script-289277046.html), you can write a script to navigate to the cloned repository and modify contents.

Comment: Thanks @Jeyanthan I, but is there a way without any installation on the machine. I am restricted to make any changes to the infrastructure. Anything that needs to be done needs to come from bamboo only.